# Разработка rss для android

Tags: android, rss

```
package android.rss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;

public class RSSFeed extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String rssResult = "";
    boolean item = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView rss = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rss);
        try {
            URL rssUrl = new URL("http://rfs.ru/rss/news.rss");
            // http://feeds2.feedburner.com/Mobilab
            //http://go-football.org/news/rss.xml
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();            
            RSSHandler rssHandler = new RSSHandler();
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(rssHandler);
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
            xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
            rss.setText(rssResult);
        } catch (IOException e) {rss.setText(e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {rss.setText(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {rss.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, 
Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("item"))
                item = true;

            if (!localName.equals("item") && item == true)
                rssResult = rssResult + localName + ": " ;

        }

        public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, 
String qName) throws SAXException {

        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            String cdata = new String(ch, start, length);
            if (item == true)
                rssResult = rssResult +(cdata.trim()).replaceAll("\\s+",  " ")+"\t";

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

много тегов . хотелось видет текс и заголовок.без технич инф.

Comment: а вопрос собственно в чем?

Comment: все работает.я знаю что не висло нужно все в отдельном потоке.вопрос не в это это я сделаю.как избавиться от лишних тегов и техн инф в отображаемом тексте ленте

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос наверняка в том, почему не работает.

Ответ: потому что нельзя в основном потоке работать с интернетом